# Voicemails cutting off in freeswitch

Tags: pbx, freeswitch

We are using a freeswitch PBX.  Any incoming voicemail getting left is being cut off after 60 seconds - i.e. the call is actually getting disconnected at that point.  Regular calls are not, just voicemail.

I checked, and the vm-disk-quota parameter is not set, which according to https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_voicemail#vm-disk-quota means that there is no limit.  Is there anywhere else this cut off might be configured?  I haven't seen anything at our SIP provider (voip.ms) to configure this, and any forum posts I've seen re: doing this at voip.ms seem to imply that it's not done there, it's just at the PBX level.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to "call_timeout" variable which has a default of 60 seconds. If call can't be answered before call timeout, it simply hangs up. You should answer the call before sending to voicemail if you don't.

https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Variable_call_timeout